# How to save the asin result in a short variable?

Tags: c, floating-point, trigonometry

Say I have two functions `f1` and `f2` and I want to get phase change between them in a short variable:

```
short  x=15615, y=24045;
short angle =0;

angle = asin((y-x)/0xFFFF);
angle = angle * 180/M_PI;

printf(" the winkel is : %d \r\n" , ( short)( angle));
```

I get only `0` no matter what I change! Any idea what I 'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `(y-x)/0xFFFF` always give 0.

Comment: Please look at Data Types .. don't use short, use float

Comment: apart from the always-zero division, angle is a short so the return value of is truncated to an integer before the conversion to degree, therefore it can't be correct anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

y and x are `short`s, therefore their difference will be in [-65535, 65535] range. Dividing (y-x) by an int will result in an *integer division* in which it almost always return 0, because `|y-x| <= 0xFFFF`. You need a floating-point division by casting either side of `/` operator to float or double

```
angle = asin((y-x)/65535.0); // or angle = asin((y-x)/(float)0xFFFF);
```

Here still another problem arises. `asin` returns a double in  [-pi/2,+pi/2] range, therefore you need to use a floating-point type to retain it's precision, otherwise the radian angle will be be converted to an int in range [-1, 1]

```
double rad_angle;
short angle; // no need to initialize it here

rad_angle = asin((y-x)/65535.0);
angle = rad_angle * 180/M_PI;

printf("The winkel is %d\n", angle); // no need to use `'\r'` here because `'\n'` will automatically be converted if needed
```

Comment: @Luu thanks for your answer it does make sense but  it still not working

Answer (score 3):

(y-x)/0xFFFF always give 0.

assume `short` is 16-bit. there is no way for `(y-x)` to exceed `0xFFFF`, and `0xFFFF` is of type `int`. so it will always evaluates to 0.

try this instead:

```
((float)(y-x))/0xFFFF
```

Comment: this makes sense, thanks for the answer, but would it help if I changed x and y datatpe

Comment: @Engine it will definitely help.